# merge debug resources FAILED

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-styles, android-debug

I'm using Android Studio and I have this error during the build of the project:

> :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>   Unsupported node 'item' in file C:\Users\Mh2\Desktop\IlMartino2doppiofinal\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml

I tried to clean and rebuild the project but it seems not to be the solution.
Here there is my styles.xml file:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"/>

        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

        <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_drawer</item>
        <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_drawer</item>

        <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/black</item>

        <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        -->

        <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
             which is used to tint widgets -->


        <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
             colorControlHighlight & colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/purple</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/red</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/darkred</item>
        <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@color/darkorange</item>



</resources>
```

How can I find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

here:

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"/>`

you closed it with `/>`

You should make it like

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item........

</style>
```